# Border aligned to box

Tags: html, css, border

i designed in sketch a sidebar with four rows inside, each of them is separate with an border.

I would like to know is its possible to get borders like these or not?

I attached a pic of my design, so ya could see what exactly i mean.

[image]

Comment: Please add `HTML` and `CSS` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can handle it with an `:after` element in css.

Here is an example

```
.demo:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 2rem;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    border-left: 2px solid #000;
    height:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #BB67E0;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size:30px;
  color:#fff;
}
div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 2px;
  height: 80px;
  background: black;
  left: -10px;
  top: 10px;
  box-shadow: 220px 0 0 0 black;
}
div:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  width: 180px;
  background: black;
  left: 10px;
  top: -10px;
  box-shadow: 0 120px 0 0 black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>content div</div>
```